# Create HTML dynamically from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

need short way for dynamically input text based on data .. 
like; get data from query is 80 data , and create 80 input text within different name .. eg: menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4 ........ menu80 .

```
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu1" name="menu1" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga1" name="harga1" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>
                    <select id="jumlah1" name="jumlah1" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu2" name="menu2" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga2" name="harga2" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>
                    <select id="jumlah2" name="jumlah2" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu3" name="menu3" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga3" name="harga3" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>
                    <select id="jumlah3" name="jumlah3" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu4" name="menu4" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga4" name="harga4" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah4" name="jumlah4" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu5" name="menu5" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga5" name="harga5" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah5" name="jumlah5" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu6" name="menu6" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga6" name="harga6" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah6" name="jumlah6" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu7" name="menu7" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga7" name="harga7" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah7" name="jumlah7" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu8" name="menu8" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga8" name="harga8" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah8" name="jumlah8" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu9" name="menu9" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga9" name="harga9" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah9" name="jumlah9" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu10" name="menu10" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga10" name="harga10" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah10" name="jumlah10" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu11" name="menu11" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga11" name="harga11" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah11" name="jumlah11" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu12" name="menu12" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga12" name="harga12" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah12" name="jumlah12" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu13" name="menu13" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga13" name="harga13" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah13" name="jumlah13" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu14" name="menu14" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga14" name="harga14" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah14" name="jumlah14" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu15" name="menu15" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga15" name="harga15" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah15" name="jumlah15" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu16" name="menu16" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga16" name="harga16" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah16" name="jumlah16" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu17" name="menu17" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga17" name="harga17" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah17" name="jumlah17" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu18" name="menu18" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga18" name="harga18" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah18" name="jumlah18" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu19" name="menu19" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga19" name="harga19" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah19" name="jumlah19" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu20" name="menu20" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga20" name="harga20" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah20" name="jumlah20" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu21" name="menu21" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga21" name="harga21" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah21" name="jumlah21" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu22" name="menu22" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga22" name="harga22" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah22" name="jumlah22" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu23" name="menu23" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga23" name="harga23" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah23" name="jumlah23" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu24" name="menu24" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga24" name="harga24" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah24" name="jumlah24" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu25" name="menu25" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga25" name="harga25" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah25" name="jumlah25" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu26" name="menu26" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga26" name="harga26" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah26" name="jumlah26" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu27" name="menu27" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga27" name="harga27" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah27" name="jumlah27" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu28" name="menu28" type="text" readonly>


                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga28" name="harga28" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah28" name="jumlah28" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="item-content">

            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title item-input">
                    <input id="menu29" name="menu29" type="text" readonly>

                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <input id="harga29" name="harga29" type="hidden" class="hrg" readonly>

                    <select id="jumlah29" name="jumlah29" class="jml item-input">
                        <option disabled selected>Jumlah</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='hidden' class='amount'>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

check fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r5hta8ng/1/

Comment: What is your actual question? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Utkanos i need short way from manually type input name=menu1, name=menu2,name=menu3, name=menu4

Comment: Please edit the question. State clearly what you are trying to achieve, what you've tried, and, specifically, what's not working. Don't make us have to work just to understand your situation.

Comment: @Utkanos can u check at fiddle and scrolling for the results ? u can see empty input text, right ? i need input text is created automatically appropriate from data .. if row menu1 till menu50 is fill at mysql . and calling with jquery on page .. and 50 input text is created

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, a little code is indeed helpful but this is overkill. Consider posting a small sample rather than a code wall for better results.

Comment: All you want is a [mcve] with all irrelevant code removed and as simplified as possible to replicate issue. Also a  better explanation of the problem would help. Note that opening your demo it is not clear what the issue is

Comment: please check this : https://edoofx.000webhostapp.com/get_menu.php?id=89 .. u can see only row menu1 - menu17 is fill .. in this case ,  i need create input text based on fill row .. if only 17 menu fill . and create input text <input type="text" name="menu1"> till <input type="text" name="menu17"> , but not typing manually

Comment: No... the objective here is not to need to go to some website and try to figure out what is what there. That's not how things work here. Questions need to be self contained with a minimal representation of the issue. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question.

Comment: okay, the simple is . 'How i can create 108 input text within javascript ? and input name in sequence ?, eg: menu1 menu2 menu3 menu4 menu5'

Comment: [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43455734/edit) and demo to reflect that specific problem and minimal representation of it. Also read [ask] for better understanding of using the site

Answer (score 0):

This will loop thru all the elements that site returned and create an input textbox with the text of each element and the name of each menu used (menu1, menu2, etc.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = parse("id");
    $.get("https://edoofx.000webhostapp.com/get_menu.php?id=89", function(data) {
        var note = $.parseJSON(data);
        for(var i=0;i< 100; i++){
          if(note["menu"+i] != ''){
                $('#appendItems').append('<input type=\'textbox\' name=\'menu'+i+'\' value=\'' + note["menu"+i] + '\'></input>').append('</br>');
          }
        }
    });
}); //document ready
```

Working Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/r5hta8ng/4/